# Explain UDP packet from tcpdump?

Tags: networking, iptables

I have get UDP packet from tcpdump:

```
0x0000:  4500 0039 6019 0000 7511 1bf5 25cb 6d53  E..9`...u...%.mS 
0x0010:  b221 8466 697d 6987 0025 c8ce 1570 0200  .!.fi}i..%...p.. 
0x0020:  23e1 0080 2321 1017 2215 303e 5a67 217e  #...#!..".0>Zg!~ 
0x0030:  18ab ed80 5154 e267 23                   ....QT.g#
```

Can you explain me these three parts?

1.

```
0x0000
0x0010
0x0020
0x0030
```

2.

```
4500 0039 6019 0000 7511 1bf5 25cb 6d53  
b221 8466 697d 6987 0025 c8ce 1570 0200  
23e1 0080 2321 1017 2215 303e 5a67 217e  
18ab ed80 5154 e267 23
```

3.

```
E..9`...u...%.mS
.!.fi}i..%...p..
#...#!..".0>Zg!~
....QT.g#
```

Where data here (UDP Layout)?

How can i use u32 module in iptables to block specific data?

Thanks.

Comment: I know that link-only answers are bad, so see  http://networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/udp.htm , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol , http://jeff.nieusma.com/docs/network/ip_packet.html

Answer (score 1):

Every Datagram is wrapped into several TCP/IP layers so your hexdump contains details about headers and after that the actual datagram (payload).

What I can tell about your packet (notable things), from IP Header:

```
- communication is over IPv4;
- IP header has 20 bytes;
- Length = 57 bytes (IP Header + IP Datagram):
- - IP Header has 20 bytes -> IP Datagram has 37 bytes;
- - IP Datagram = Next Protocol Header + Payload;
- next protocol is 0x11 which means UDP;
- Source IP: 37.203.109.83;
- Destination IP: 178.33.132.102;
```

From UDP header (UDP header has just 8 bytes):

```
- source port: 27005
- destination port: 27015
- Length (UDP Header + Payload) 37 bytes;
- - UDP Header = 8 bytes;
- - Payload = 29 bytes;
```

Payload:

> 1570 0200 23e1 0080 2321 1017 2215 303e 5a67 217e 
>   18ab ed80 5154 e267 23

Regarding your questions

> Where data here (UDP Layout)?

Yes

> How can i use u32 module in iptables to block specific data?

See reference below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528385/iptables-how-do-i-block-a-specific-udp-packet

Comment: Many thanks man for this information, I get the point.

Comment: In order to understand how I got the values from your hexdump you should read about IP Header, TCP Header, UDP Header, ICMP Header etc...and terminology for Offset, High nibble, Low nibble.

Comment: chrysstyann, Thanks i already read about it and i'am able now to analyze any UDP packet and use u32 filter. But can i ask how to translate this data (payload) to something i can understand? Is this the whole data that client send to my server?